# How to generate minified CSS from SASS file using Gulp

Tags: css, angular, sass, minify, concatenation

i'm developing my first Angular 2 app and i'm using the following folder structure:

[image]

I'm trying to set up the configuration file of Gulp (it is my first time) and i would get one minified `style.css` file from different `.scss` file.

I began to write the following code:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({
        style: 'compressed'
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});
```

Can you tell me the best way to concat the generated minified CSS file into unique CSS file?

**EDIT:**
I reach the same with the following:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create  `style.scss` file & import other `.scss` files in it . Like this

```
@import "first.scss";
@import "second.scss";
@import "../third.scss";
...
```

after replace second line in your code with this

```
gulp.src('src/style.scss')
```

output must be one `style.min.css`

Comment: Ok, in this way i can create some "index" .scss files that contains some `@import`. Then how to concat all index files to one CSS file as output?

Answer (score 0):

This below does not include the `sass` task but you get the idea for one css file:

```
var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/**/*.js",
    ts: webroot + "app/**/*.ts",
    minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/**/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
};

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```